# Android Lenovo custom ui

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I faced with strange behavior of UI in Android 4.2.1 Lenovo P780 device.
It doesn't react on customizing of ActionBar tab style. Also it uses own progress indicator and maybe some other ui widgets.

Below are screenshots from P780 and all other test devices. Styles for ActionBar were generated by http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/. **But for Lenovo P780 styles customizing doesn't change anything.**

[image: Lenovo device]

[image: All other devices - expected behavior]

Below is a part of Manifest where style was set and styles.xml content

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>
```

Lenovo P780 OS/firmware information:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally problem is solved!
After migration to new Lollipop support libraries and using styles with `AppCompat` parent everything works fine.